# Subtract a number of capital letters in a row from a string

Tags: perl

I have a string which can contain letters and/or numbers, and I want to identify if it has 10 capital letters in a row and subtract them if they exist:

Example :

```
my $string = "MyString-MetadataDZEDDMWKQMsomeothertext";
```

I want to identify that this string contains 10 capital letters one after each other (`DZEDDMWKQM`) and subtract them

```
my $final_string = "MyString-Metadatasomeothertext"
```

I managed only to be able to subtract a fixed amount of characters, but it was not helpful for what I need.

Comment: It sounds like English is not your first language. You might have trouble finding a solution online because _substract_ (actually, _subtract_) is no the right word for this. You want to _substitute_ (with an empty string) or simply _remove_. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a [regular expression substitution](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s).

```perl
my $string = 'fooABCDEFGHIJbar';
$string =~ s/[A-Z]{10}//;

print $string;
```

The regex pattern contains two parts:

- `[A-Z]` is a character group containing all upper case letters, from `A` to `Z`
- `{10}` is a quantifier, meaning repeat the the previous thing exactly 10 times

You can learn more about regular expressions in Perl in [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre). The [regex tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) is useful too.